# Marketing Cloud - Reply Mail Management

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

I have been asked to set up reply mail management for a  BU. I am completing the fields a the top of the screen (and I have read the help article) but I dont understand what this actually means for the system if I put something in these fields. Some of the BU's have multiple address domains that they can send from:

[image]

Comment: Do you have Sender Authentication Package? Without it, RMM won’t work

Comment: yes I have SAP package for this BU

Comment: Did you select to utilize RMM on the SAP form (https://senderauth.marketingcloud.com/)? If that is selected then this section will automatically completed by Salesforce once the SAP form is submitted and approved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Email Display Name**: The reply name appears in the From field of the subscriber email client, such as Microsoft Outlook, when the subscriber replies to your email. Do not use an email address as the Email Reply Name. To encourage interaction with your subscribers, use an individual's name from your organization, such as a member of your customer service group.
- **Reply Subdomain**: The subdomain is the portion of your URL that points to Marketing Cloud email reply rules. For example, a company with an email address structure of name@example.com creates a subdomain of reply. That company then adds it to the box provided onscreen to create reply.example.com.
- **Email Reply Address**: The reply address appears in the From name of your subscriber's email client when the subscriber replies to your email. While this information appears in the format of an email message, it is not a valid email address on its own. The address directs the reply to RMM for processing. Define this address in the Reply Mail Management feature or via a sender profile. If you use a sender profile to define the email reply address, you can enable the email message to use a multitude of email reply addresses.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

If the BU has multiple domains that are used for sending, you still can send using those domains, but all replies would go to the same **Email Reply Address**. If you need the replies to go to the sending domain, you might want to look into **Dynamic RMM**:

> Reply Mail Management (RMM) can direct valid replies to those dynamic
>   From names instead of the default email address. Contact your
>   Marketing Cloud account representative if you want to use this feature
>   with your RMM configuration. This feature requires AMPscript
>   knowledge.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_dynamic_rmm_configuration.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need dynamic reply mail management.

use a content area in content builder and use ampscript to fill in the fields you can pull this data from a data extension of code them directly in the content area. reference that in the from address and name. ex. `%%=ContentBlockByID("23432")=%%`.

make sure you echo out the variable you want to fill in the content block ex. `%%=V(@myfromaddress)=%%`